# Terminal closes immediately after opening

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I wanted to run the command

```
/bin/bash --login;rvm use 1.9.3
```

everytime I opened the terminal.

So, I added the command in the n terminal, Edit > Preferences > Tab Title and command > Run a custom command of my shell. But I set it to exit terminal when command closes. How do I undo this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command in XTerm

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on terminal icon and go to preference option. And then change your previous settings. And all will be good afterwards.